# Is it expected for an empty house to use 14 kWh per day?

Tags: electrical

We have bought a new house but we haven't moved in yet. I've received our electric bill several days ago and it shows our electric bill on average is about 14 kWh per day but it seems the only working appliance in our house is the refrigerator.

Can someone suggest whether this is expected or not?

Comment: @DanD. Thanks Dan. But that seems to be 1.411 kWh / day instead of 14.11 kWh / day?

Comment: Depending on a large number of factors, there's a possibility that the electric utility was just guessing the electrical usage. (They're usually pretty good guesses, and they send someone by every so often anyway.) You can check by comparing the meter number on your bill with the actual meter. If the meter is behind the number on the bill, that's what happened.

Comment: @user3757614: Thanks for the reply. But in this case I can be sure that these are actual readings for two reasons. 1) The statement itself has a "Meter Read Type" column and it shows "Actual Read" in this statement. 2) I've also manually checked the meter reading several times and the amount of electricity we've consumed is similar to the meter readings shown.

Comment: Well, worth checking.

Comment: Did you figure out what it was?

Comment: @Grant: Sadly no. I've turned off all the circuit breakers one by one and everything seems to be normal so I'm thinking maybe it is because I forgot to turn off some of the incandescent light bulbs...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That does seem high for an unoccupied building, but not imposssible.  It works out to about 5 amps drawn 24 hours a day.

These are plenty of things that might be adding up.  The biggest ones would be:

- Electric hot water. Even if you dont use it, it keeps getting reheated
- AC or electric heat, if they were left on or there is a faulty thermostat turning them on
- Lights left on.
- Fridge running non stop - an empty fridge with a small leak in the door seal might do that.
- Small appliances like keurig coffee makers that preheat the water all day

Easiest thing to do is watch the hydro meter.  It is easier if you still have an old non-smart meter with a spinning disk, but you can just write down the numbers.  Unplug the fridge and turn everything else off, check what the electric meter says and check again in half an hour.

If it has moved something is still using power.  If you can't figure out what, narrow it down by turning circuit breakers off one by one or a group at a time until it stops.

Comment: Thanks Grant for the detailed reply. We're using the a natural gas water heater so we can eliminate that possibility right now. We don't have small appliances like coffee makers. I've tried to turn all the circuit breakers off except for the refrigerators and the numbers look normal - about 2 kWh per day so there must be something else... :p

Comment: @derekhh in that case, I'd start turning them back on one by one, and seeing which one(s) make the usage go up.  You'll probably find one of them powers something you didn't think of, like an electric towel warmer, or a whole house fan in the attic.  Or maybe a secret grow op hidden behind a false wall.

Comment: Thanks Grant. I'm following your suggested approach right now. :)